# Добавление постов в mysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой. Написал добавление постов в mysql, но, к сожалению, они не добавляются. Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка.

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
if(isSet($_POST['content_txt']) && isSet($_POST['content_title'])) {
$txt=$_POST['content_txt'];
$thema = $_POST['content_title'];
$user_id=$_SESSION['login_user'];
mysql_query("insert into post(uid,text) values ('$user_id','$txt')");
}
else {
echo "bad";
}
?>
```

Вот скрипт, передающий значения обработчику:

```
     testButton: function(buttonName)
        {
            var text = $('.redactor-editor').html();
            var title = $('#thema').val();
            var dataString = 'text='+ text + '&title=' + title;
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'posting.php',
            data: dataString,
            cache: false
});
        }
```

Подключение к базе и название таблиц правильное. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @OverLoader при каких условия ajax срабатывает?

Comment: Скопируйте и процитируйте сюда сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: Ajax срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку. Данные отправляются, но добавление не происходит в базу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax отправка:

```
$(function(){
    $('#form-id').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var message = $('#id-textarea').val();
        var title = $('#id-title').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'posting.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { message: message, title: title },
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.error) {
                    alert(response.error);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Текст записан!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP Обработчик:

```
if($_POST) {

    $error = null;

    if (empty($_POST['text']))
        $error .= 'Текстовое поле не заполнено!';

    if ( ! $error) {
    // пишем в базу
    }
    exit(json_encode(array('error' => $error)));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вот такой запрос  базу считается нормальным? 


    mysql_query("insert into post(uid,text) values ('$user_id','$txt')");

Comment: @OverLoader, даб но еще бы обработать данные перед записью функцией `mysql_real_escape_string()`